# How to create ".dll.a" and ".a' file

Tags: windows, gcc, cygwin, mingw-w64, fftw

I am currently compiling a program involved reference to fftw3 library. I intend to compile it with Mingw-w64. I understand that I should put the fftw3.h in the /include folder and "fftw3.a" and "fftw3.ddl.a" files into the /lib folder for compilation by gcc.

However from the online available source, I can only find the source code for fftw3 library or the "dll" file to the best. I am wondering how I can find or make the "fftw3.a" and "fftw3.ddl.a" files.

Comment: cygwin already has the `mingw64-x86_64-fftw3` package. It contains the `libfttw3.dll.a` shared import libary https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/mingw64-x86_64-fftw3/mingw64-x86_64-fftw3-3.3.5-1

Comment: @matzeri, thanks very much for the very kind comment. I have noticed this and tried. It worked. It is just that I have to use Cygwin to do this. I am not sure if mingw-w64 alone would be enough.

Comment: you can copy the content of `usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/` on your mingw installation. It should work

Comment: @matzeri, thanks, thanks, that is a fair solution. Just still wonder how dll.a and a are made.

Comment: as usual: from source `configure` and `make`